# Does exact match location has precedence over no modifier used?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have config:

```
server {
    listen       ${PORT};
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
    location = / {
        index bootstrap.html;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:5000;
    }
}
```

I expect that static file bootstrap.html will be served on `/`, because docs says that exact match has precedents over not modifier used. But this config tries to get bootstrap.html on http://host.docker.internal:5000 not from disk. What I do wrong?